# Inform the node owner when the Jenkins node is down in Grafana or Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts

I have setup the Grafana/Prometheus. I am monitoring the nodes status in Grafana and when a node is down I will be informed because I have setup my email as a contact point but I have to inform the user who owns the node that his/her node is down. To remove the middleman ( which is me ;) ) How can I set up the alert in Grafana for each node?

Thanks,
Bharath

The workaround is to install the matilwatcher plugin and add the user email in the configuration which will notify when the node status changes. But I would like to centralize the notification system in Grafana.